# PhantomJS wildcard file deletion

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

I've searched the net all over for this but unfortunately I could not find the answer I am looking for. Do phantomjs support wildcard deletion? This is the example I found in their site.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var toDelete = 'someFile.txt';

fs.remove(toDelete);

phantom.exit();
```

But this is not what I want. I want to delete multiple files of the same type. Say for example I want to delete all the (*.png)png of this directory. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no `glob`-like method in PhantomJS File System module, but you can simply read contents of a directory and delete matching files.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = "/path/to/folder/to/clean/"; // needs trailing slash
var list = fs.list(path);

for(var x = 0; x < list.length; x++){

    var file = path + list[x];
    if(fs.isFile(file) && file.match(".png$")){
        fs.remove(file);
        console.log("Deleted " + file);
    }
}
```